# progress bar for large export of sql to excel process

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel, progress-bar

I need to create a progress bar for my export process.

I already have a code for exporting. However, the larger the data to be exported the longer the system hangs and won't provide information to user that it is doing something.
what i needed is to create a progress bar to at least inform the user that a process is being completed.

I don't know where to put it and what to put.

I am using VS 2013 Ultimate and Excel 2013.. here is my code for export.

```
Try
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\NGPdata.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message & " here")
End Try
Try
    Dim res As MsgBoxResult
    res = MsgBox("Process completed, Would you like to open file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        Process.Start("D:\NGPdata.xlsx")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

as well as the code it required.

```
Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Using GC.Collect() is not recommended and hardly ever useful. Let the GC handle its own scheduling; "premature optimization is the root of all evil" in about 95% of cases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a ProgressBar in the Form.
2. Modify properties of ProgressBar

   ```
   value = 0
   Maximun = 100
   ```

And your code should be:

```
    ...
    Dim Increment as Single
    Dim IntMax, currentIndex as Long
    currentIndex = 0
    intMax = (DataGridView1.RowCount - 2) * (DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1) * DataGridView1.ColumnCount

    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()

                Increment= Int(currentIndex / intMax)
                ProgressBar1.Increment(Increment)
                currentIndex += 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
```